# Adding values of Edit boxes?

Tags: xpages

This seems like such a simple question.

I have several Edit boxes on my xPage.  The user may or may not enter an integer value.  The fields are set to accept an integer.

I want to to total all of the values in those fields.  I have the following, that works,  but it seems awfully inefficient.  Is there an easier way to do this?

```
var DeliveryTotal:int = getComponent(ctlName).getValue() == null    ? 0 : parseInt(getComponent(ctlName).getValue());
var Delivery100s:int = parseInt(getComponent("inputTextDelivery100s").getValue());
var Delivery50s:int =  parseInt(getComponent("inputTextDelivery50s").getValue());   
var Delivery20s:int =  parseInt(getComponent("inputTextDelivery20s").getValue());
var Delivery10s:int = parseInt(getComponent("inputTextDelivery10s").getValue());
var Delivery5s:int = parseInt(getComponent("inputTextDelivery5s").getValue());
var Delivery1s:int = parseInt(getComponent("inputTextDelivery1s").getValue());  


DeliveryTotal = isNaN(DeliveryTotal) ? 0 : DeliveryTotal;
Delivery100s = isNaN(Delivery100s) ? 0 : Delivery100s;
Delivery50s = isNaN(Delivery50s) ? 0 : Delivery50s;
Delivery20s = isNaN(Delivery20s) ? 0 : Delivery20s;
Delivery10s = isNaN(Delivery10s) ? 0 : Delivery10s;
Delivery5s = isNan(Delivery5s) ? 0 : Delivery5s;
Delivery1s = isNan(Delivery1s) ? 0 : Delivery1s;

var totalEntered = Number(Delivery100s) + Number(Delivery50s) + Number(Delivery20s);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you compute the values client side? If so then you could use the following jQuery. It selects all the fields with id starting with inputTextDelivery and adds the value together.

Number(0 +..) will convert blanks to 0 and 0123 will be converted to 123

```
var sum=0;
$('[id^=inputTextDelivery]').each(function() {
    sum += Number(0+$(this).val());
});
```

If not you can certainly remove the block of code checking for 0 by

```
var totalEntered = Number(0+Delivery100s) + Number(0+Delivery50s) + Number(0+Delivery20s);
```

Comment: Thanks Marky.  That certainly simplifies it.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You may simplify the script a bit. Make array of component names. Then reduce your code into two lines with getValue() and ? condition and iterate it inside loop for those component names array. It could be a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for in the way of simply taking the values in each field and adding them together.